# I received Pull Request in GitHub from contributor. But I'd like to make some changes to it. How to do that and still give him credit when merging?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch, pull-request

I received a Pull Request for my GitHub repo from a fellow contributor. But I would like to make some changes to it before merging. It is not clear to me how to do that and then still merge under his name to give him credit. I can only merge the whole thing as he submitted. What am I missing?

I would like to do that in the command-line (i.e. terminal) with the appropriate sequence of git commands. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It was a response to a previous comment that recommended a force push.  Looks to be outdated now.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch and check out the PR branch, and make and switch to a new branch. Make the desired changes and add and commit. Push. Make a PR asking to merge your new branch into the first PR branch. There are now two PRs that give credit where credit is due, and they can be merged in any order.

Comment: Can't I just merge my branch into his branch and then merge his branch to main? Also, if you would be so kind as to list the terminal `git` commands for doing that, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You can do whatever you like. But if you are allowed to just merge your branch into his branch, without any checks-and-balances, then this is not a true pull request workflow any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the changes into a `work-in-progress` branch. Switch to that branch locally, make the adjustments, push the branch and create a new pull request.

1. Go to [https://github.com/{YOUR_NAME}/{YOUR_REPO}/branches](https://github.com/%7BYOUR_NAME%7D/%7BYOUR_REPO%7D/branches) and hit
   the new branch button.
2. Go to the open pull request page [https://github.com/{YOUR_NAME}/{YOUR_REPO}/pull/{NUMBER}](https://github.com/%7BYOUR_NAME%7D/%7BYOUR_REPO%7D/pull/%7BNUMBER%7D) and hit edit button in the top right.
   Switch the target branch to the `work-in-progress` branch.
3. Merge the pull request.
4. Go to your local machine, update your repo `git pull` and switch to the
   `work-in-progress` branch.
5. Make your changes and push them.
6. Create another pull request for your `work-in-progress` branch and     merge it.

You have merged all the contributed commits along with your changes.